# Unable to start splash activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app and I want to relauch the splash activity at some point in the application. Normally starting a new Activity is a pretty simple task, but for some reason I am not able to restart my `SplashActivity`. Here is what I've got so far:

**Manifest**

```
 <activity
            android:name=".controller.welcome.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I have also tried to add the following `intent-filter`:

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

and that did not help.

I am attempting to start the activity from my `onCreateView` from within a fragment:

```
 @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(myStuff == null || mViewModel == null){
            Log.d(TAG, "Restarting application....");
            try{
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SplashScreenActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.d(TAG, "Problem starting activity: " + e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        ...
```

I have also tried using `getActivity` and `getApplicationContext` to create the `Intent`. I'm sure that I'm missing something small, like intent filter, but I can't seem to locate it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you got an exception when tried to start `SplashScreenActivity`?

Comment: Probably, you want your Splash Screen Activity to also be the DEFAULT one. I had the opposite problem, and I fixed it by setting my Main Activity to be the DEFAULT one.

Comment: In which version android you are trying

Comment: @DimaKozhevin, no I haven't got an exception. Clifford, I'm using 7.x for the current phone.

Comment: The method `SplashScreenActivity.onResume()` is called?

Comment: Not that I have seen. Nothing from `SplashActivity` has been called.

Comment: The fragment that calls `startActivity` is in the same activity?

Comment: No, the fragment lives in `MainActivity` and I'm trying to call `SplashActivity` @JuanCruzSoler

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashScreenActivity.class);
```

I believe that 'getContext()' differs from 'this'.